# Why is SSH trying to access a -cert's that do not exist?

Tags: macos, ssh, public-key

Why is a simple ssh to a GoDaddy Server trying to use a "-cert" file.  It does not exist?  id_rsa and id_dsa exist.  The -certs do not?  Where is it getting the information to be including a -cert?

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to example.com [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: How would it know they don't exist if it doesn't look for them?

Comment: Thanks Kenster.. That's my question.. Why is it attempting to finda  -cert that is not there?

debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never did get an answer for this but somehow it cleared up as I'm no longer getting this error.